# how to display a table in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i want to display a table (like a footbal table) in silverlight in a windows phone 7 app. i was reading a bunch of articles on the www, but couldn't really understood what's the best way to approch this issue. 
i am new to silverlight, so some code would be really awsome. I keep the data i have to display in some Lists (List), but i could change this...
any advices? thank you in advance!

naic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the form factor [of almost all mobile devices] lists are much easier to read.
You will see this in the default templates for WP7.

There are various ways you can create a "table" in Silverlight. (I assume you are refering to a league table.) The easiest would probably be a grid or a templated list.

If you really must do this I would suggest having 2 different ways of displaying the data depending on screen orientation.

- In the portrait orientation I would show a list with minimal statistics.
- In the landscape orientation I would show a table layout which could include multiple statistics as there is more horizontal space.